# R - Using sqldf to query multiple values from one column in dataframe

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I'm pretty new to R and trying to use the SQLDF package to query a dataset. I have constructed the following query, which works perfectly and displays the correct data:

```
sqldf("select AreaName, TimePeriod, Value from df2 where Indicator == 'Obese children (Year 6)' AND AreaName == 'Barking and Dagenham'",
    row.names = TRUE)
```

But I would like to pull the data for 'Richmond upon Thames' as well as Barking and Dagenham. I have tried this:

```
AND AreaName == 'Barking and Dagenham', 'Richmond upon Thames'
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : error in statement: near ",": syntax error
```

And I have also tried:

```
AND AreaName == 'Barking and Dagenham' AND AreaName == 'Richmond upon Thames'
```

Which creates the new dataframe as expected but when I view it, it is empty. I know it is not an issue with the name 'Richmond upon Thames' as I have entered this into the first statement by itself instead of 'Barking and Dagenham' and it works perfectly.
Could anybody help me with what the correct structure should be?

Many thanks

Comment: Try `AreaName IN ('Barking and Dagenham', 'Richmond upon Thames')` may be?

Comment: That worked perfectly thankyou so much! I used  sqldf("select AreaName, TimePeriod, Value from df2 where Indicator == 'Obese children (Year 6)' AND AreaName IN ('Barking and Dagenham', 'Richmond upon Thames')",
        row.names = TRUE)